# Reverse Match Search in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, reverse

I need to do a match/index search in reverse  right to left

each cell with have an x i need do go from right to left find what column the x is in and report the position so can then go to the top of that column and pull that data.  I basically need to find out what column is the last X in.

```
A         B        C        D    E          F      G      H      I       J
State   27-Aug  28-Aug  29-Aug  30-Aug  31-Aug  1-Sep   2-Sep   3-Sep   4-Sep
VI       X        X       X        X       X      X
```

in above example 3 rows 10 columns if  i want to see that the last X is in Column G(7) then i use the index to go to that column(7), row A  to 1-sep as the answer.

Comment: =INDEX(1:1,1,COUNTIF(2:2,"X")-1) assuming there are no gaps

Comment: @User91504 that is a good option, please put it as an answer.  It may or may not work for the OP but future readers may find it useful.

Comment: @ScottCraner sure thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will find the last cell with a value, regardless of value:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$J$1,MATCH("zzz",A2:J2))
```

[image]

---

If you want to find the last `X`, regardless of what is or is not in any of the other cells, then use this formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$J$1,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(A2:J2)/(A2:J2="X"),1))
```

One note: this is an array type formula and will be slower than the prior formula.  If you only have one it will not make a difference.  If you have hundreds you will see a difference.

But if you have other text strings after the `X` and you want the `X` then it is the way to go.

[image]

Comment: That works perfect Thank you so much!!!  I will always have an X in the columns, i might have a few spaces in the middle but this work with the spaces in the middle.  Again Thank you so much for the help on this!

Comment: @JoshuaGoodman please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: FYI  I was able to get the first answer to work =INDEX($A$1:$J$1,MATCH("zzz",A2:J2))

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing please? COLUMN(A2:J2)/(A2:J2="X")

Comment: `COLUMN(A2:J2)/(A2:J2="X")` either returns the column number or an error. the `(A2:J2="X")` will resolve to `1` if `X` is found or `0` if it is not.  Dividing by `1` returns the numerator while dividing by `0` returns an error.  The `6` tells the formula to ignore all errors and as such the Large function only looks at the column numbers that have `X` in the range.  @Absinthe

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev then you are doing it wrong.  Either formula will ignore gaps.  The first will return the value of the last text value.  The second will return the value at the last `x`.  You are probably misunderstanding how to use the formula.  Neither care if there are gaps or not.

Answer (score 1):

try out

```
=INDEX(1:1,1,COUNTIF(2:2,"X")-1)
```

Assuming there are no gaps within the stream of X's

Comment: there will be gaps in the list so i need to use the solution from Scott Craner

Answer (score -1):

```
=MATCH(2,IF(A2:J2="x",1,FALSE))
```

This is an array formula.
This will give you last position of x. Then, like you indicated, put the result inside INDEX function and you should be good. I like this option because i can put any condition inside the if statement, like >0.

Comment: This Match does not work on unsorted data, the data given match here must be sorted. Match works on unsorted with exact match, when third argument is 0. But then match finds first match